# How to store variable on jenkins server and change them through jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having a hard time finding a way where I can store some global variable on the Jenkins server and then keep updating it through the jobs. My use case is whenever there is any new build available, it triggers downstream jobs. Also, there are some jobs that run periodically in a week. I want to store the latest build number on the server so that whenever the periodic job runs, it runs on the latest build.
I have tried saving global variable but I can change it within a job using envInject but that change is not reflected globally.

Comment: Re: "want to store the latest build number on the server", why not juat get the dynamically from the latest build?

Comment: Yes, that would have been the best way to do it but with the current setup, I am unable to check the latest available build. That would require more changes.

Answer (score 1):

One option for storing parameters on the server scope is using the **Global Environment Variables**.
They are available via: Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables.
These parameters are available for all jobs and can store parameters in a 'server wide' scope that will then be available everywhere.
You can then update or set them via code using the following groovy method:

```
@NonCPS
def updateGlobalEnvVariable(String name, String value) {
    def globalNodeProperties = Jenkins.getInstance().getGlobalNodeProperties()
    def envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

    if (envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0) {
        def envVarsNodePropertyClass = this.class.classLoader.loadClass('hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty')
        globalNodeProperties.add(envVarsNodePropertyClass.newInstance())
    }
    envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars().put(name, value)
}
```

This function should better be placed in a Shared Library from which it can be called by every job that needs to update the Global parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/ plugin which does exactly what you're looking for.

You can also search for plugins with the keywords of your choice here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?sort=relevance&categories=&labels=&view=Tiles&page=1&query=